# Insert file content at the beginning of a minified file

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, source-maps

I have done a quick test with doing it after the compilation, but this of course breaks the source maps line numbering.

The closest flag I found in --help is `--output_wrapper` which takes a string (not filename) as a parameter, which means the command is going to be quuuuite long.

How can I insert content of a file into the beginning of the minified file and keep the source maps working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use an index map souce map to build a source map that refers to the original maps of the concatenated files.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool other than Closure-compiler. This heavily depends on your build environment as to what tool would be best suited. Closure-compiler does not handle basic file concatenation.